# Zend 2 + Doctrine 2 indefinite number of connections

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Currently I am working on ZF2 application using Doctrine 2. The application deals with multiple users and each user has an access to the application through his own subdomain, for example:

```
user1.example.com
user2.example.com
...
user10.example.com
```

Also, each user has his own database, corresponding to his subdomain, let say:

```
db_user1
db_user2
..
db_user10
```

The configuration is quite trivial having one or two doctrine connections:

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'user',
                    'password' => 'pass',
                    'dbname'   => 'database',
                )
            ),
           // Here we can define several configuration alternatives, 
           //use different keys for each one
            'orm_alternative'=> array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'db_user1',
                    'password' => 'db_pass1',
                    'dbname'   => 'db_user1',
                )
            ),
        ),
     ) 
  );
```

Obviously in my case the above configuration is useless, since I have indefinite numbers of connections to different databases.

So, my question is what is the best way to setup Doctrine to work with indefinite numbers of connections, based on the subdomain.

Cheers,

Vasil Dakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution for my own question is to get the EntityManager instance via Service Factory as the following example:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Doctrine\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

class EntityManagerServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $subdomain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

        $paths = array(ROOT_PATH.'/module/Application/src/Application/Entity');
        $account => $this->getAccountTable()->findOneBy(array("subdomain" => $subdomain));

        $isDevMode = true;
        $dbParams = array(
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user'     => $account['user'],
            'password' => $account['password'],
            'dbname'   => $account['dbname'],
        );
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
        $config = Setup::createConfiguration($isDevMode);
        $driver = new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader(), $paths);
        AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists');
        $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
        $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

        return $entityManager;

    }
}
```

It works fine and hope to help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Config load order look like that

```
1.application.config.php
2.$module->getConfig()
3.$module->get{,*}Config() (or ServiceListeners)
4./config/autoload/{,.*}{global,local}.php
```

So You could add every user config in `Module.php` in `getConfig()` function.

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return array(
        'user1' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host'     => 'localhost',
                'port'     => '3306',
                'user'     => 'db_user1',
                'password' => 'db_pass1',
                'dbname'   => 'db_user1',
            )
        )
    );
    //of course you have access to service locator here and could generate your dbconfigs
}
```